How to get each matrix item to run different commands with github actions?
I'm trying to get the matrix I created to run two different commands. I've tried a bunch of different syntax and I can't seem to get it. It always runs the first command but I only want it to run "If All Tests, Run UI Playwright Tests" on matrix = UI and then run "If All Tests, Run API Playwright Test"` on matrix = API. And I want them to run in parallel. Can someone help?
name: Run Automation On Demand

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      URL:
        description: 'Which url do you want to run this one?'
        required: true
        default: 'xxxx'
      choice:
        type: choice
        description: Which suite do you want to run?
        options:
        - All Tests
        - All UI
        - All API
        - Login

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest-xlarge

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [21.x]
        automation-type: [UI, API]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci
    - run: npx playwright install chromium
    - name: If All Tests, Run UI Playwright Tests
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.choice == 'All Tests' }} && ${{ matrix.automation-type.UI }}
      run: URL=${{ github.event.inputs.URL }} npx playwright test playwright/dashboard --workers=8
    - name: If All Tests, Run API Playwright Tests
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.choice == 'All Tests' }} && ${{ matrix.automation-type.API }}
      run: npx playwright test playwright/api --workers=20

Also tried:
    - name: If All Tests, Run UI Playwright Tests
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.choice == 'All Tests' }} && ${{ matrix.automation-type == 'UI' }}
      run: URL=${{ github.event.inputs.URL }} npx playwright test playwright/dashboard --workers=8
    - name: If All Tests, Run API Playwright Tests
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.choice == 'All Tests' }} && ${{ matrix.automation-type == 'API' }}
      run: npx playwright test playwright/api --workers=20

Also tried:
    - name: If All Tests, Run All Playwright Tests
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.choice == 'All Tests' }}
      run: |
        ${{ matrix.automation-type.UI }} URL=${{ github.event.inputs.URL }} npx playwright test playwright/dashboard --workers=8
        ${{ matrix.automation-type.API }} npx playwright test playwright/api --workers=20


You could use matrix object, with a command line associated to each automation-type. Something like used here

I don't actually follow how I can tie that into what I have. Can you elaborate a bit more using my scenario?

You could do something like this in your matrix strategy: automation-type: [{"name": "UI", "command": "npx ..."}, {"name": "API", "command": "npx ..."}] and then use directly in the matrix job ${{ matrix.automation-type.name }} and ${{ matrix.automation-type.command }} to use those variables dynamically based on the strategy configuration.

Nice! I got it to work. Is there a way to not have the job in the GitHub Actions UI not display the command but just the name?

I don't think there is, this is the standard behavior when using matrix strategy =/

As you can use objects in the matrix strategy list (it's not limited to string values or numbers), in your case you could add a "command line" value associated to each automation-type name.
Here is an example:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest-xlarge
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [21.x]
        automation-type: [{"name": "UI", "command": "npx ..."}, {"name": "API", "command": "npx ..."}]
    steps:
      - run : |
          echo ${{ matrix.automation-type.name }}
          echo ${{ matrix.automation-type.command }}

That way, you'll be able to manipulate those data directly as dynamic variables in your matrix job by using ${{ matrix.automation-type.name }} and ${{ matrix.automation-type.command }}
Note that this will display the command line in the Github UI on the workflow run
